# Is there a way to compare hash values with iteration?

Tags: ruby, input, hash

A user inputs the scores for a game such as `"Rockets 89 Suns 91"`, and I'd rank the teams based on wins, but in order to know which team is the winner, I have to compare the two values. I might have a hash:

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 2}
```

and I would want to compare `teams[:yankees]` and `teams[:mets]`, but since the keys are input by the user and may change, I don't know what key to point, so I cannot do `team[:yankees] <=> team[:mets]` explicitly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Give example of input and output if possible.

Comment: maybe - `teams[teams.keys[0]] <=> teams[teams.keys[1]]`

Comment: do you know exactly how many keys/values pairs will be contained in the `teams` hash? Is it a fixed number?

Comment: I think it'll always be two key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
teams = { yankees: 5, mets: 2 }
max_score = teams.values.max
winning_team = teams.select { |key, value| value == max_score }
# => returns { yankees: 5 }
```

You might want to add a check if the score is equal between the 2 teams. Also, think about if the score is equal, should your method returns 2 winning teams or none at all? It might be easier for your code to handle 1 or 0 team, and not 1 or 2 winning teams.

Comment: You don't manage the case when both teams have the same score

Comment: because it was not asked, because it is pretty easy to do, because I would add it if the OP asks for it, because I'm kinda lazy today.

Comment: What was asked was to compare the scores with the "<=>" operator. But I get what you meant ;)

Comment: Whatever, the OP asked to find the team with the highest score. I provided a solution, with a warning in case of a tie. I did my job here on StackOverflow, OP will mark my answer as correct if it fits his needs. Nothing to argue about in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want, but I suppose you want the list of the winners (both teams when it is a tie).

#### When one team wins

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 2}

teams.group_by(&:last).max.last.map(&:first) # => [:yankees]
```

#### When it is a tie

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 5}

teams.group_by(&:last).max.last.map(&:first) # => [:yankees, :mets]
```

Comment: if you use `group_by(&:pop)` it avoids the need to `map` again at the end. e.g. `teams.group_by(&:pop).max.last.flatten`

Answer (score 1):

Why not define a method to handle this:

Making this code reusable will allow you to compare not only game scores but also use this for things like standings, or any other statistics you can place in the same format of `key =>value`.

You could do something like this:

```
def winner(teams)
  winners = teams.group_by(&:pop).max_by(&:shift).flatten
  if winners.count > 1 
     "It's A Tie between the #{winners.map(&:capitalize).join(' and the ')}!" 
  else
     "Winner is the #{winners.shift.capitalize}!"
  end
end
```

Then you can just pass your Hash in

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 3}
winner(teams)
#=> "Winner is the Yankees!"
teams[:mets] = 5
winner(teams) 
#=>  "It's A Tie between the Yankees and the Mets!"
```

You can compare as many teams as you'd like this way

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 5, phillies: 5}
winner(teams)
#=> "It's A Tie between the Yankees and the Mets and the Phillies!"
```

If you wanted to return an `Array` of the teams as others seem to think you do the modification would be simple:(just take out the if statement)

```
def winner(teams) 
  #could also use: (same result)
  #  teams.group_by(&:pop).max.last.flatten 
  teams.group_by(&:pop).max_by(&:shift).flatten
end
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 3} 
winner(teams)
#=> [:yankees]
teams[:mets] = 5
winner(teams)
#=> [:yankees,:mets]
```

**How this works**

Group the Hash by the scores (when passed to `group_by` this enumerator becomes `[[:yankees,5],[:mets,3]]` `pop` then pulls the score part out and groups the team(s) by this value)

```
teams.group_by(&:pop)
#=> {5=>[[:yankees]],3=>[[:mets]]}
```

Then find the max by the keys (when passed to `max_by` this becomes `[[5,[[:yankees]]],[3,[[:mets]]]` `shift` then pulls the score part out and uses it as the comparison to return the team(s) with the max score)

```
.max_by(&:shift)
#=>[[[:yankees]]]
```

Then we just flatten the `Array`

```
.flatten
#=> [:yankees]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
teams = {yankees: 5, mets: 2}

def compare_scores(teams)
  if teams.keys.length == 2
    return teams.values.first <=> teams.values.last
  else
    raise StandardError, "Should have exactly two teams"
  end
end

def get_winner(teams)
  result = compare_scores(teams)
  case result
    when 1
      return teams.keys.first
    when -1
      return teams.keys.last
    when 0
      return teams.keys
  end
end
```

`compare_scores` returns the result of the "<=>" operator between the scores of both teams, and raise an exception if there is more or less than 2 teams.

`get_winner` returns the winner if there is one, and an Array of both teams  if they had the same score. Of course, you can choose to return whatever you want instead ;)

Comment: This does not do the trick it simply returns -1, 0, or 1 which would then have to be handled after the fact as well.

Comment: I actually thought exactly the same thing after I posted it. I have added another function handling the result of the first one. But the question was actually only to compare the scores.

Comment: instead of `teams[teams.keys.first]` why not simply `teams.values.first` and save some overhead.

Comment: That's true. I was stuck in the keys I don't know why.

Comment: This also seems very limited to only allow the comparison of 2 teams ( i know that is what was stated) but this means for other similar comparisons like standings or home runs or anything that would involve a larger data set the OP would then need another method to handle these.